# How can I speed up loading of XML documents from disk?

Tags: xml, performance, dom, xml-parsing, vb6

I'm trying to speed up a VB6 XML parser.  The XML files to be parsed are stored on my local hard drive.  The `If xDOC.Load(objFile.Path) Then` statement below is taking a very long time, according to my profiling results.  That statement took 34.5 seconds overall during processing of a small batch of 100 XML files.  A sample XML file is [here](http://donnees-data.opic-cipo.gc.ca/dd/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/admin-sample.zip).  Can this code be improved to speed up XML file loading, or is the loading speed constrained by the nature of the XML files themselves?

```
Option Explicit

Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object

Dim xDOC As MSXML2.DOMDocument

Dim xPE As MSXML2.IXMLDOMParseError

Sub Main()

Set xDOC = New DOMDocument

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\My XML File Folder")

For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
    Set xDOC = New DOMDocument
    xDOC.async = False

    If xDOC.Load(objFile.Path) Then
        ' process the file
    Else
        ' XML file failed to load; log error and continue with next file
    End If

   Set xDOC = Nothing

Next objFile

Set objFolder = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your XML is fine, actually it's quite small, and loads very quickly, with the proper document settings.

I did notice the DTD, which is re-downloaded from http://patents.ic.gc.ca/cipo/dtd/ca-patent-document-v2-0.dtd every time you download a file. Moreover, the DTD itself embeds other DTD files, so you're likely downloading them too.

MSXML XML does a lot of extra stuff by default, but if your XML is known to be "good", then the fastest way to load it is to set the following values to false before calling Load().  This way you're only validating that the XML is well formed.

```
var doc = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument");
doc.validateOnParse = false;  // don't validate
doc.resolveExternals = false; // don't even download external files (DTDs...)
doc.preserveWhiteSpace = false; // don't try to preserve formatting.
doc.load("somexml.xml");
```

Hope this helps you out, and you can translate it over the VB6

Comment: Thank you.  That gave me an immediate 3.3x speed improvement.  It's still slow, but I'll take any improvement (I'm shredding millions of files).  [I've spent a lot of time on VB optimization tricks, database index tuning, query execution plan monitoring, stored procedure code rewrites, adding indexed hash columns to database tables and so on.  None of that has made even the tiniest bit of difference; everything is swamped by the time taken to load the individual XML files.  My server is loafing, with nothing to do while it waits for the next file to load in my client-side app.]

Comment: On my team, we do a lot of similar work, XML shredding, getting XML into MS-SQL databases.  Try to minimize the trips to the database as much as possible (group XML files together, parse XML in the stored procedure, group commits), happy to connect if you're interested in discussing the project further.

Comment: Thanks again William.  Does my comment "everything is swamped by the time taken to load the individual XML files" make sense in the overall context of what I'm doing?  I'm already minimizing database selects/updates/deletes as much as I can.  I had thought that database index rebuilds (due to inserts/deletes on multi-million row tables) were causing my performance problems, but they're trivial in comparison to the time required to load the individual XML files.  I should add that my local hard drive (on which the XML files are stored) is an SSD.

Comment: In my previous comment "index rebuilds" should be "index updates".

Comment: Sounds a little unusual that XML loading is the slow part, especially with such a small XML file. From your initial post, you indicated 100 XMLs file loads in 34 seconds, with a 3x improvement I guess that's around 10 seconds.  How many files are you trying to load?  Be careful to time each section of your code (for example, elimate all DB operations), to identify the slowest parts.  I guess you've already done this?

Comment: Using Windows Scripting Host (cscript.exe), I'm able to load your sample XML file 100 time in 0.17 secondsm and 1000x in 1.5 seconds.  See my 2nd answer below.  I wonder if you don't have some bad VB6 ActiveX interop stuff happening?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214078/discussion-between-william-walseth-and-brw).

Answer (score 1):

Run this with the following command in windows

```
cscript.exe testperf.js testfile.xml 1000
```

Here's the testperf.js

```
var aArguments = WScript.Arguments;
var xmlDoc;
var xslDoc;

function loadXMLFile( strFileName ) {
    var xml = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.FreeThreadedDOMDocument");
    xml.setProperty("SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:ms='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt'");
    xml.validateOnParse = false;
    xml.resolveExternals = false;
    xml.preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    if( !xml.load( strFileName ) ) {
        var strError = "";
        var facility = xml.parseError.errorCode>>16 & 0x1FFF;
        var code = xml.parseError.errorCode & 0xFFFF;
        strError = 'Error loading: ' + strFileName + '\r\n';
        strError += xml.parseError.reason;
        strError += "Facility: " + facility + " Code: " + code + "\r\n";
        strError += xml.parseError.srcText + "\r\n";
        strError += xml.parseError.url + "\r\n";
        strError += "Line: " + xml.parseError.line +  " Postion: " + xml.parseError.linepos + "\r\n";
        throw new Error( xml.parseError.errorCode, strError );
    }
    return xml;
}

try {
    if( aArguments.length < 2 ) {
        WScript.Echo( "Usage: testperf file.xml loadcount" );
        WScript.Quit( 1 );
    }
    var strStatus = 'Loading XML';

    var dtStart = new Date().valueOf();
    var nLoop = parseInt( aArguments(1) );
    for( i = 0; i < nLoop; i++ ) {
        xmlDoc = loadXMLFile( aArguments(0) );
    }
    var dtStop = new Date().valueOf();
    WScript.Echo( nLoop + " XML loads took " + parseFloat( (dtStop - dtStart) / 1000 ).toFixed( 2 ) + " seconds.");

}
catch( e ) {
    WScript.Echo( 'Error in file:' + aArguments(1) + '\n' + e.number + " " + e.description );
    WScript.Quit( 1 );
}
```